# Deserialize XML containing a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dictionary

I have an XML file containing identifiers that I would like Get, the xml look like

```
<Dictionary 
  x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object"
  xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>    
  <List x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" x:Key="key" Capacity="4">     
    <x:Int32>60371408</x:Int32>      
    <x:Int32>60371409</x:Int32>   
  </List>  
</Dictionary>
```

The identifiers that I want to get is 60371408, 60371409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution :
[image]

Thank you for your reaction :D

Answer (score 0):

Create an [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
```

...then deserialize. You haven't specified what form this XML is in, whether you have a string or a stream, for example. Here's how you'd deserialize an XML string:

```
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
var dict = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Now you have your `Dictionary<string, object>`, but since values are plain objects, you'll need to cast the values:

```
var list = (List<int>)dict["key"];
```

Comment: Hi Jacob thank you for your reactivity but i have thit issue when try to instanciate the xmlserializer with Dictionary: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary type is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement dictionary = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Dictionary").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace xNs = dictionary.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("x");

            var results = dictionary.Descendants(xNs + "Int32").Select(x => (int)x).ToList();

        }

    }
}
```